# Do while statement not accepting variable

Tags: java, do-while

I am trying to make a program that takes positive integers from the user and finds the maximum until the user enters a negative number. I have to use a do while loop. It won't accept the variable in the while part of the statement. I don't understand why this is, because I checked and I should have the correct amount of brackets.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a number: ");

do {
   int currentnumber = 1;
   int number = in.nextInt();
   if(currentnumber < number) {
      currentnumber = number;
   }
   if(number > currentnumber) {
      currentnumber = number;
      System.out.println("Max number is: " + currentnumber);
   }
} while(number > 0);
```

Edit: Once I fixed the number issue. The program will print "Enter a number: " but when a number is entered it doesn't do anything

```
 Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.println("Enter a number: ");

int number; 
do{
int currentnumber = 1;
number = in.nextInt();
    if(currentnumber < number){
        currentnumber = number;}
    if(number > currentnumber){
        currentnumber = number;
        System.out.println("Max number is: " + currentnumber);

    }
}while(number > 0);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I noticed is that you are setting `currentnumber` in both less than and greater than cases. If you are attempting to determine the `max` input value then you only need to assign that value if it is greater than the current max value.

One other reason it "doesn't do anything" is likely because the number you have entered is less than the `currentnumber`. In that case your program doesn't output anything but goes back to accepting input.

Also consider moving the output asking the user for input within the loop. Then each iteration will re-prompt the user for input.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

int currentMax = 0;
int number = 0;
do {
   System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
   number = in.nextInt();
   if(number > currentMax) {
      currentMax = number;
      System.out.println("Max number is: " + currentMax);
   }
} while(number > 0);
```

Comment: Awesome that worked! Do you think it might be best to add an error statement if the user inputs a negative number?

Comment: Glad I could help. If you would like output for negative number you could simply do that after the while loop since that is the exit criteria for the loop.

Answer (score 1):

declare `number` outside of do block so that while() can access it

Comment: Thank you that did solve that problem, but my program won't do anything when an integer is inputted.

Comment: can you explain what do you mean by program won't do anything

Comment: what do you mean when an integer is inputted?

Comment: When I run the program it will print "Enter a number: ", but when you enter a number it does nothing.

Comment: does this code compiles without assignment to `number` at declaration time ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. If your asking if the code compiles without giving number a value when I declare it, then yes.

Answer (score 1):

No, because in Java, local scopes are defined by `{}`(*block*). If you declare `number` *inside* the `do` block, it won't be accessible outside.

Notice that the condition `(number > 0)` is outside of the `do` block.

**What can you do?** You can declare `number` before the `do-while`:

```
int number = ...;

do {
    ...
} while (number > 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

To use a variable in the conditional part of a `do-while` loop, the variable must have scope outside the loop--it must be defined outside the loop.

```
int number;
do{
    int currentnumber = 1;
    number = in.nextInt();
    if(currentnumber < number) {
        currentnumber = number;
    } if(number > currentnumber) {
        currentnumber = number;
        System.out.println("Max number is: " + currentnumber);
    }
} while(number > 0);
```

This is no different from any other loop.

```
while (number > 0) {
    int number;
    // do stuff
}
```

That loop will have obvious problems.  But if we rewrite it to:

```
int number = 1;
while (number > 0) {
    // do stuff 
}
```

The problems are gone.

The same logic applies to your `do-while` loop.

You declared `number` inside the loop and it therefore only exists within the loop.  In order to use it outside of the body of the loop (which includes the loop's conditional statement), it must be declared outside the loop.